# XHTML to java conversion best way

Tags: java, xhtml, xml-parsing, jaxb

We have a req to convert xhtml file to java objects(I can not change the source to change the format or type). This is about address and the first three tags can be empty if the same person has two addresses in the system. What would be the best way to convert this into java objects? jaxb or any other? Can you give me a simple illustration how you do this..

For ex:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>john</td>
<td>doe</td>
<td>1/1/09</td>
<td>cincinnati, OH</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Atlanta, GA</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>john1</td>
<td>doe1</td>
<td>1/1/89</td>
<td>cincinnati, OH</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Parse the data with a XML parser and populate it into a java object ? Is there a specific question here ?

Comment: My hunch is that there isn't an off the shelf library that can convert *this* XHTML to Java objects (the nodes aren't correlated to property names), so it looks like SAX parsing is your best bet.

Comment: You could use a tool like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) to query this as HTML

Comment: Before doing sax parsing and manually mapping I wanted to check if I can do anything like Jaxb XML parsing.( Jaxb.unmarshal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class so15933614 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "so15933614.html";
        print("Fetching %s...", url);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(url), "UTF-8");
        Elements rows = doc.select("tr");
        for (Element row : rows) {
            print("---------");
            Elements data = row.getElementsByTag("td");
            print("First Name:%s", data.get(0).text());
            print("Last Name:%s", data.get(1).text());
            print("Date:%s", data.get(2).text());
            print("City:%s", data.get(3).text());
        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Fetching so15933614.html...
---------
First Name:john
Last Name:doe
Date:1/1/09
City:cincinnati, OH
---------
First Name:
Last Name:
Date:
City:Atlanta, GA
---------
First Name:john1
Last Name:doe1
Date:1/1/89
City:cincinnati, OH
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You can use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to map things by position:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlPath("td[1]/text()")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlPath("td[2]/text()")
    private String lastName;

    @XmlPath("td[3]/text()")
    private String date;

    @XmlPath("td[4]/text()")
    private String city;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: This solution sounds good too but for our req it won't work as we get <th> tags in this file and that tells which order the data would be. That's a new change.